# Configure git completion for checkout to only show local branches?

Tags: git, zsh

I'm not sure where git completion is implemented but I'm on MacOS, running zsh, and oh-my-zsh. If I type `git branch -v` I see I have 4 local branches

```
> git branch -v
  dangling-pointer       ce141cd55 Metal: Fix dangling pointer in IntermRebuild
* fix-occlusion-query-m1 67a147feb Metal: Fix Occlusion Query bug on M1
  main                   93c0c90db Suppress the failing egl test to unblock roller
  readpixel-speed-test   3ebef5614 Metal:Read Pixels Speed Test
```

But if I type `git checkout <tab>` I get this

```
❯ git checkout <tab>
zsh: do you wish to see all 6036 possibilities (776 lines)?
```

Those other 6032 possibilties are tags and a few other related things like `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`

Checking another repo, just one branch

```
❯ git branch -v
* master 8ce048a build
```

but auto-complete shows

```
❯ git checkout <tab>
zsh: do you wish to see all 186 possibilities (34 lines)?
```

Which if I pick yes is

```
❯ git checkout
FETCH_HEAD                                   fix-uniform-block-padding-issue              origin/dev                                   test                                       
HEAD                                         lgtm-test                                    origin/fix-uniform-block-padding-issue       uniform-tree                               
ORIG_HEAD                                    master                                       origin/lgtm-test                             v4.21.2                                    
allow-sharing-arrays                         origin/HEAD                                  origin/master                                v4.22.0                                    
cap-sphere                                   origin/allow-sharing-arrays                  origin/test                                  v4.22.1                                    
dev                                          origin/cap-sphere                            origin/uniform-tree                                                                     
v0.0.1   v0.0.9   v0.0.17  v0.0.25  v0.0.34  v0.0.42  v1.5.1   v2.1.0   v2.6.1   v3.0.2   v3.4.1   v4.0.1   v4.5.1   v4.9.1   v4.11.2  v4.14.0  v4.17.0  v4.19.5                
v0.0.2   v0.0.10  v0.0.18  v0.0.26  v0.0.35  v1.0.0   v1.5.2   v2.1.1   v2.6.2   v3.1.0   v3.5.0   v4.1.0   v4.5.2   v4.9.2   v4.11.3  v4.14.1  v4.18.0  v4.20.0                
v0.0.3   v0.0.11  v0.0.19  v0.0.27  v0.0.36  v1.1.0   v1.6.0   v2.1.3   v2.7.0   v3.2.0   v3.6.0   v4.2.0   v4.6.0   v4.9.3   v4.11.4  v4.14.2  v4.18.1  v4.21.0                
v0.0.4   v0.0.12  v0.0.20  v0.0.29  v0.0.37  v1.2.0   v1.6.1   v2.2.0   v2.8.0   v3.2.1   v3.7.0   v4.3.0   v4.7.0   v4.9.4   v4.11.5  v4.15.0  v4.19.0  v4.21.1                
v0.0.5   v0.0.13  v0.0.21  v0.0.30  v0.0.38  v1.3.0   v1.7.0   v2.3.0   v2.8.1   v3.2.2   v3.7.1   v4.3.1   v4.8.0   v4.10.0  v4.12.0  v4.15.1  v4.19.1  v4.21.2                
v0.0.6   v0.0.14  v0.0.22  v0.0.31  v0.0.39  v1.4.0   v1.7.1   v2.4.0   v2.8.2   v3.3.0   v3.8.0   v4.3.2   v4.8.1   v4.10.1  v4.12.1  v4.15.2  v4.19.2  v4.22.0                
v0.0.7   v0.0.15  v0.0.23  v0.0.32  v0.0.40  v1.4.1   v1.8.0   v2.5.0   v3.0.0   v3.3.1   v3.8.1   v4.4.0   v4.8.2   v4.11.0  v4.13.0  v4.16.0  v4.19.3  v4.22.1                
v0.0.8   v0.0.16  v0.0.24  v0.0.33  v0.0.41  v1.5.0   v1.9.0   v2.6.0   v3.0.1   v3.4.0   v4.0.0   v4.5.0   v4.9.0   v4.11.1  v4.13.1  v4.16.3  v4.19.4                       
8ce048a  -- [HEAD]    build (4 days ago)
5a4e7b5  -- [HEAD^]   bump to v4.22.1 (4 days ago)
5c85f3a  -- [HEAD^^]  changelist (4 days ago)
9a19a3f  -- [HEAD~3]  fixed missing return types in `vertex-arrays.js` (4 days ago)
05807c5  -- [HEAD~4]  build (8 weeks ago)
b35e44a  -- [HEAD~5]  bump to v4.22.0 (8 weeks ago)
297e0d1  -- [HEAD~6]  add samples to AttachmentOptions (8 weeks ago)
aa7fe4a  -- [HEAD~7]  build (8 months ago)
a3cb143  -- [HEAD~8]  update docs (8 months ago)
7944f37  -- [HEAD~9]  build (8 months ago)
9850f58  -- [HEAD~10] typo (8 months ago)
bf3b5c1  -- [HEAD~11] build (8 months ago)
74eb006  -- [HEAD~12] typo (8 months ago)
859ebd0  -- [HEAD~13] build (8 months ago)
8718e95  -- [HEAD~14] typo (8 months ago)
11d1c92  -- [HEAD~15] remove unused modules (8 months ago)
f8141e9  -- [HEAD~16] move old tests to new test harness (8 months ago)
b8a7b1a  -- [HEAD~17] build (8 months ago)
190c144  -- [HEAD~18] bump to v4.21.2 (8 months ago)
2a3aeff  -- [HEAD~19] fix for Safari's lack of lookbehind assertions (8 months ago)
```

I'm not sure why it's showing the last 20 commits (or whatever that is at the end)

Is there a way to configure git auto-complete so it only shows local branches? As it is the completion is mostly useless *for me* unless I already know the branch names so that I can type a few characters and filter the completions.

## Update:

Some people have suggested `--no-guess`. That gives a smaller list but not small enough.

```
❯ git branch -v
  backup-packpixels                           923bd8756 Metal:Speed up BGRA8 to RGBA8 copy for readPixels
* buffersubdata-perf-test                     8b2807fc0 Metal: Use Vulkan style BufferSubData impl
  check-cb-order                              7e92ef8aa Metal: Fix for not submitting command buffers in order
  clear-surface                               924f6de7d Metal:Clear Backbuffer when Robust Resource Init enabled
  main                                        29d18b303 [behind 39] Revert "Vulkan: Use VK_EXT_primitive_topology_list_restart"

> git checkout <tab>
zsh: do you wish to see all 6486 possibilities (2176 lines)? 
> git checkout --no-guess
zsh: do you wish to see all 3298 possibilities (1113 lines)?
```

That's still 3294 entries too many with `git branch -v` shows just 4 branches

```
❯ export GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1
❯ git checkout 
zsh: do you wish to see all 6450 possibilities (6450 lines)?
```

No effect

although I see it referenced in `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/gitfast/git-completion.bash`

Also there is no

```
__gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs...
```

in the `git-completion.bash` file.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: no I have not figured it out

Comment: I don't know how to make Git do this, but I wrote a tiny script to solve the problem. It lists local branches and you enter a number to switch to one of them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77565613/4376

Answer (score 1):

The post
[Disable auto-completion of remote branches in Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623649/disable-auto-completion-of-remote-branches-in-git-bash)
has several suggestions.

Here is an
[answer by erik.weathers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626043/165358):

> I'm assuming that you are using the `git-completion.bash` script, and
> that you **only** care about `git checkout`.
>
> To accomplish this, I just changed one line in the definition of the
> `_git_checkout ()` function in `git-completion.bash`:
>
> ```
> <         __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
> ---
> >         __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads '' $track)"
> ```
>
> My understanding is that this only affects the tab-completion action
> (because of its location within the `*` case of the switch-case
> statement).

Another
[answer by Toland Hon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778220/165358)
did some more:

> Following erik.weathers' answer above, I made the following change so
> autocompletion can work for both local and remote based on the current
> prefix. By default, it'll only search local, but if I specify
> `origin/…` it'll know I want to search remote branches too.
>
> In the `_git_checkout ()` method, change
>
> ```
> __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> # only search local branches instead of remote branches if origin isn't specified
> if [[ $cur == "origin/"* ]]; then
>     __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
> else
>     __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads '' $track)"
> fi
> ```
>
> Of course, you can change `origin` to something else or you can have
> it search through through a list of remote prefixes if you have more
> than 1.

The accepted
[answer by VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747486/165358)
is to use:

```
git checkout --no-guess ...
# or:
export GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1
```

Comment: `--no-guess` didn't work. `export GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1` didn't work. The scripts above are for bash not oh-my-zsh? There's a `git-completion.bash` in `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/gitfast/git-completion.bash` and editing it affects competions but it's `_git_checkout()` method does not have any calls to `__gitcomp_nl`. There were some places that reference "refs", I changed them to "heads" but no change in behavior. There's also `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.zsh` but I haven't checked if that's being used.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet answer is, yes, there is.

This blog post provides easy to follow instructions on how to achieve it: https://cmetcalfe.ca/blog/git-checkout-autocomplete-local-branches-only.html

**NOTE**: In the article, Carey suggests creating a new alias for checking out local branches, i.e. *checkoutr*

I'd strongly suggest following this approach as there may very well be times when you need to see the full list of options - so separating out the commands is ideal.

**Also**, if you used brew to install git on MacOS then the configuration file you're looking for is likely here:

```
$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
```

If you don't come right following this info, let me know and I'll do some deeper diving.

Comment: The edits suggested in the article you linked to do not match [my `git-completion.bash`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/gitfast/git-completion.bash)